# How do I determine if a cell contains non-western text? (Excel)

Tags: excel

I have a column containing titles that feature both English / basic Latin character-based titles e.g: **John Smith** and non-western / extended Unicode character-based titles e.g: **黄小琥** OR **Björk**

How can I check whether a cells in column B are the 'plain' English titles or the opposite?

Any pointers / suggestions would be gratefully received!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Feel free to edit my question if I have the terminology for the character sets incorrect!

Comment: off topic; I've flagged for migration to excel.SE.

Comment: @djechlin Please explain, I'm not sure what that means. As in http://excel.se ?

Comment: Check the `CODE("X")` function. It may be of help here.

Comment: Have you looked into checking their character codes for values outside the range for english?

Comment: @AshBestos Sorry I'm being crazy.  I decided there was an excel stackexchange and I have no idea why.  Anyway, I think this would fend better on superuser.com.

Comment: @djechlin No worries, I may have something to go on from the comments, if not I'll try superuser. Cheers all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could enter this UDF in a VBA code module.

```
Function IsLatin(Str As String) As Boolean
IsLatin = True
For i = 1 To Len(Str)
    IsLatin = IsLatin And Abs(AscW(Mid(Str, i, 1)) - 64) < 64
Next i
End Function
```

Then if your text is in Column A, enter in cell B1 `=IsLatin(A1)` and fill down.

...alternatively in Excel 2013 you could use this array formula confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER:

`=AND(UNICODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<128)`

also filled down from B1.

*Note*: `CODE` can't be used for this as it translates unicode to latin letters, for example  `=CODE("α")` and `=CODE("a")` both return 63

Answer (score 1):

When I tried @lori_m's VBA code on strings that have mixed English and Japanese I got an overflow. Not sure exactly why. I modified it slightly and it works for me now:

```
Private Function is_latin(ByVal str As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer

    is_latin = True

    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        If Abs(AscW(Mid(str, i, 1)) - 64) >= 64 Then
            is_latin = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

It also exits with false the first time it finds a non-latin character. This isn't the best type of coding practice in a FOR loop but it will speed up processing for longer strings.