# How to check if a string (or cell) has kajji characters inside it?

Tags: excel, vba, unicode

I work for a Japanese company.  As such a majority of the excel tables sent to me are in mostly Japanese.  So I have created an excel macro that prompts the user to select a range of cells they want translated.  The macro loops through the range of cells grabbing the cell value, copying it into the Google Translate Text Box, waits for the translation, copies the translation, and sets the cells value to the translation.

Now all of this is working and I can translate any range I throw at it.  The issue I am having is the amount of time it takes to translate a document.  I have done everything I can with speeding up the connection to google.  The next thing I see slowing the macro down is the fact I cannot figure out a simple way to determine if a cell contains any Japanese (hiragana, katakana, kanji).  So I am looking for a function that essentially does this:

```
Function isJapanese(cell as Range)
     If cell.Value is Japanese Then
            isJapanese = True
     Else
            isJapanese = False
     End If
End Function
```

I am already checking if the string contains latin letters or not (which is making it skip some cells), certain symbols, and any other character or string I can think of that is unique to only English cells.

Below is the code I have so far (I am using a user form to get the variables for the translation function)

```
Function Translate_Range(rng As String, in_exp As String, out_exp As String) As Boolean
Dim japCheck As Boolean, japCount As Integer, cellAddress As String, transText As String, langDesired As String, wkb As String, sht As String, searchRange As Range, doneCheck As Boolean
doneCheck = False
wkb = ActiveWorkbook.Name
sht = ActiveSheet.Name
Workbooks(wkb).Worksheets(sht).Activate
japCount = 0
japCheck = True
Set searchRange = Range(rng)
For Each cell In searchRange
    If cell.Value <> "" And InStr(cell.Text, "mm") = 0 And InStr(cell.Text, "±") = 0 Then
        japCheck = IsAlpha(cell.Text)
        If japCheck = True Then
            GoTo NextIteration
        Else
            transText = translate_string(cell.Address, in_exp, out_exp)
            ActiveSheet.Range(cell.Address).Value = transText
        End If
    End If
NextIteration:
    Next
    doneCheck = True
    Translate_Range = doneCheck
End Function

Private Function translate_string(cell As String, input_exp As String,  output_exp As String)
Dim str As String
str = ActiveSheet.Range(cell).Value
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate "http://translate.google.com/#" & input_exp & "/" & output_exp & "/" & str
    Do Until IE.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
Do Until result_data <> ""
    CLEAN_DATA = Split(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(IE.Document.getElementById("result_box").innerHTML, "</SPAN>", ""), "<")
    For i = LBound(CLEAN_DATA) To UBound(CLEAN_DATA)
        result_data = result_data & Right(CLEAN_DATA(i), Len(CLEAN_DATA(i)) - InStr(CLEAN_DATA(i), ">"))
    Next
Loop
IE.Quit
translate_string = result_data
End Function

Private Function IsAlpha(strValue As String) As Boolean
    IsAlpha = strValue Like WorksheetFunction.Rept("[a-zA-Z]", Len(strValue))
End Function
```

I feel like there has to be a Unicode protocol for kanji characters.  I am just woefully inexperienced when it comes to things like this (I am a mechanical engineer who makes excel macros to make my life easier, so my knowledge of technical programming topics like this is lacking sorry)

Comment: You don't have to start MS Internet Explorer to do this. You can make the HTTP request directly in VBA, google for "VBA HTTP Request", you should get many examples.

Comment: Does [this SO thread/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16798887/4650297) do the trick?  It may, if hiragana, katakana, kanji are all non-Latin characters.

Comment: I am already using a version of this code that runs smoother IsAlpha does the same thing but doesn't generate overflow errors like the IsLatin function does.  The problem with this however is some cells will have latin and non latin characters mixed ex "ジャガイモは10g / m2" could be in a cell and would then be skipped. I should say I want my function to look at each piece of the string and see if it is Japanese or not.

Comment: Wernfried Domsheit thank you for that suggestion.  That is something I will have to look into in the future.

Comment: Also give free translator service a try, e.g. http://www.frengly.com/api They could be even easier to use.

Comment: Please change the title of this question! "kanji", not "kajji".

Answer (score 0):

This sub, borrowed heavily from the answer I linked to, can determine if a string has any latin characters:

```
Sub t()
Dim k       As Long
Dim myString As String
myString = Range("Z1").Value  'Edit this as needed
Dim latinChars As Long

latinChars = 0
For k = 1 To Len(myString)
    If IsLatin(Mid(myString, k, 1)) Then
        ' Has latin characters
        latinChars = latinChars + 1
    End If
Next k

If latinChars = 0 Then
    ' Doesn't have latin characters
    Debug.Print "Doesn't have latin characters"
Else
    ' Has latin characters
    Debug.Print "Has latin characters"
End If

End Sub

Function IsLatin(Str As String) As Boolean
IsLatin = True
For i = 1 To Len(Str)
IsLatin = IsLatin And Abs(AscW(Mid(Str, i, 1)) - 64) < 64
Next i
End Function
```

Comment: So this helps avoid some of the translation mistakes that occur but it is not perfect. would it be possible to lets say set up a dictionary of all possible hiragana, katakana, and kanji (this dictionary would then contain like 2500 elements) and see if any part of the string is in that dictionary? or some other structure again I'm not to savy on these things.

Comment: like set up an excel sheet with all of them inside and use the Find function or something?

Comment: Can you perhaps post some samples of your cells? What isn't the function catching? Are hiragana, katakana, and kanji characters that *are* being read as Latin?  ...And I suppose yes, if you do have a list of characters, we can always just loop through that list and see if any character in the `myString` matches a character in that array.

Comment: 容量up 
Ns91 (a 処理)
are some examples of cells the code isn't catching but the code will catch other cells with latin characters.  I think its the spacing of characters and may also be something on googles end I have not tested yet to see if kanji will show up in the translated text box before it gets translated